# My css text-align property is overriden by user agent stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have a text input field (more specifically, in my Angular app, a primeNg maskInput) for which I want to center the text.

I've correctly set the property in my css:

```css
p-inputMask {
    text-align: center;
}
```

It *is* valid and picked up by chrome, but somehow it uses the default UA stylesheet instead:

[image: Chrome dev tools]

I have the same result in Firefox.
If I add `text-align: center;` inline, it works!
I'm puzzled. If it were not valid, I'd understand. If the result were not the same on different browsers, I'd understand. If inline style didn't work, I'd understand. But it seems like it **should** work!

*Edit*: Things I've tried:

- Changing the selector to a class
- Changing the selector to all input tags
- Changing the selector to an id
- Setting the alignment as `!important`

It is not an inheritance nor specificity problem. The property *is* picked up by chrome (and simply styling `input` should have higher priority than the UA stylesheet, unless I'm mistaken).
Here is my `computed` tab:

[image: Computed style tab]

Chrome sees my property, but somehow, even if `!important` (which is the case on this capture), it deems it less important than the vanilla style.

Comment: I also tested changing the selector to something more specific, on the class, on all `input`, on an id... to no avail.

Comment: use !important to force properties : p-inputMask {
    text-align: center !important;
}

Comment: you have inheritance here. The selector should be applied to the input

Comment: @becherhenchiri you should always prefer specificity in your cascade to using `!important`. If you have to rely on it, there's something wrong with your logic.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with specificity (or at least not that I can grasp), cf my edit. Regardless, thanks for the hunch!

Comment: Ok, I feel bad about this; this had to do with specificity, kinda. I had to use Angular ::ng-deep pseudo selector.